# Can I use "take your advice" to refer to points expressed about my code?

Tags: phrase-request

My advisor had some points about my code, but I was unable to use what he had recommended. I was wondering if "take your advice" is a correct phrase for these points said about my code?

My sentences are:

> I'm sorry that I didn't take your advice about SVM and Kmeans, I don't have these toolboxes, I will download them and update the code soon.

Comment: @DCShannon: thank you for your comment, I want to say at this moment I cannot take your advice but in future I will download them and use his recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is correct, grammatically…

...however, if you were unaware of his recommendations *before* his advice was given to you, then you cannot have "failed to take his advice" - you had not been given any advice at that time.

You could only have been *unaware* of these 2 new methods/tools.
You can only take or not take advice after being advised - anything else would be precognition, or mind-reading ;)

If, after taking note of his advice, you *still* don't want to use his recommendation, then you are truly not taking his advice.

Downloading the recommended tools & re-working your project is still *taking the advice*, not dismissing it.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it a bit differently.

> **Unfortunately**, I couldn't take your advice about SVM and Kmeans, *since* I don't have these toolboxes. I will download them and update the code soon.

I don't think *I'm sorry* is necessary since (as I understand it) you could not follow his advice because you did not have certain resources, not because you just decided to do something else. As such, *Unfortunately* is sufficient to state that it was not the outcome he expected.
(Though you might still want to use *I'm sorry* if you think it is necessary due to formality.)

Also I changed the conjunctions/punctuation between phrases so it flows better. The second and third phrases are independent so there needs to be a period or semi-colon there.